# save_post action hook for comments

Tags: comments

Is there a action similar to save_post for comments?  Already tried comment_post which does not fire when clicking the update button on a comment in WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `edit_comment` hook that's fired within the `wp_update_comment()` function, called by the `edit_comment()` function when you edit a comment in the backend.

This hook is fired after the comment is updated in the database.

**Example:**

```
add_action( 'edit_comment', 
    function( $comment_ID )
    {
        // ... your code here ...
    }
);
```

Notice the following comment in the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/comment.php#L1857):

> The hook also fires immediately before comment status transition hooks
>   are fired.

I find this comment somewhat confusing, because it's actually the `get_comment` filter that's fired  immediately before the comment status transition hooks are fired within the `wp_transition_comment_status()` function. 
But it's true if *hook = action*, but I usually understand the meaning of the word *hooks* to be both *actions* and *filters*. But this was just a minor detour.

ps: My first thought/guess was `save_comment`, before I checked the source ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I use simply this, as i couldnt find other..

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'Check_commentt');          //or directly execute Check_commentt()
function Check_commentt(){
    if (isset($_POST['author']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
        //do something
    }
}
```